# Clear tool command (Clear case) for getting the versions of the files in the directory

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

In the clear case, I want versions of the file in the particular directory with complete file path. By right click on the file and after that going for properties in the file it is possible to take, but in case in the directory 100 files are there, so it will become very huge task. I want to know the clear tool command , which i can execute from the command prompt and after that I can redirect output to some text file

Example of path I am using:

```
M:\My_Project\Verif_Folder\TP\Functional_TP\ETP\  here
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the command [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), combined with a [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and [fmt_ccase option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
cd M:\Myproject\...\here
cleartool find . -type f -exec "cleartool describe \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\" -fmt \"%Xn\""
```

`%Xn`: Extended name: Same as default

> `%n` output, but for checked-out versions, append the extension @@\branch-pathname\CHECKEDOUT

The result will be the path of the file, its name, and its extended path including its current selected version.